# Which library for video and audio recording?

Tags: c++, python, video, audio, cross-platform

I am looking for a library to record images from a webcam and sound from the microphone and generate a video file (avi, mpeg or any other format).

I would prefer a cross-paltform solution (Windows, MAC and Linux) and something in C/C++ or Python.

Any recommendation and/or sample code?

Update: Folowing @Rory reccommendtation, i found [this example](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/webcam-viewer.html) of webcam viewser with Python and gstreamer. Unfortunately it requires v4l2src plugin which is not provided (correct me if I am wrong) with the Winodws build. Which plugin should be used on Windows?

Comment: Too open ended, there are hundreds of choices available.

Comment: @Steve-o: hundred of choices!? One would be enough, but I don't find any solution at the moment.

Comment: I'm interested in this too, if you found a solution please add it an an answer or edit your post with some more info to get more eyes on it.

Comment: @agf : no pb, I'll update if I have some news. It may take a little while because I don't have time to investigate more right now. Add the question to your favorites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) is an open source multimedia framework with C & Python bindings.

Comment: Gstreamer is open source, but not particularly cross-platform. They don't even distribute binaries for windows, for instance, which leads me to doubt a wide range of use case compatibility.

Comment: @stefan Songbird is a good and possibly bad example of GStreamer on Windows.  GLib just isn't too MSVC friendly.

Comment: @Rory: Thanks for pointing out gstreamer. I have already look at this lib which seems great but a bit tricky on windows. See my update. Thanks